# I Don't to want initialize a variable in foreach loop. Any other possible logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to relate with other table if there any record about *GoDownRent* exist if no then Finalizing list according to it but the problem is I NEVER want to initialize *var* in foreach loop(as I want to avoid it for a reason) but I ended up with this code.

**Code :**

```
    private CargoEntities context = new CargoEntities();

    public ActionResult Section82List()
    {
        List<IMPORTAWB> _listOfAWB = context.IMPORTAWBs.ToList();
        List<IMPORTAWB> _finalizedListForView = new List<IMPORTAWB>();

        foreach (var item in _listOfAWB)
        {
            var _GodDownRent = context.GODOWNRENTs.Where(f => f.AWBNO == item.AWBNO).FirstOrDefault();
            if (_GodDownRent == null)
            {
                _finalizedListForView.Add(item);
            }
        }


        return View(_finalizedListForView);
    }
```

Any other logic will be appreciated as it will initialize 10k *var* in code I want to avoid it with better logic.

Comment: *I NEVER want to initialize var in foreach loop(as it's not good practice)* *Is it*? Ridiculous statement about foreach I ever heard.!

Comment: Why do you consider it bad? Please explain your logic a little further. Maybe this suits CodeReview better, btw.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes brother it's not working well if there are 10000 records in ImportAWB it will initialize it 10000 times there should any other possibility for better logic.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It will Initialize itselft 1k times if there are 1k records.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `foreach`. Which means you're not using entity framework in a right way.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ridiculous statement about foreach you ever heard is because you speaking without getting the point brother.

Comment: @ShahAbdullah Come on read it again *I NEVER want to initialize var in foreach loop(as it's not good practice)* Now tell what you understand from this? You should clearly mention in the question, which you failed to do. Your question sounds like using foreach is a bad practice.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel .(JVM - 1.5.0)

A: average execution time: .074 sec(Out of loop initialization) 

B: average execution time : .067 sec(In loop initialization)

it will speed up the process but occupies much space. I want to avoid is it getting clearer now?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I edited my question as it will not say "Your question sounds like using foreach is a bad practice" Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get items which don't have corresponding rent entities in single join query:

```
var finalizedListForView =
    from i in context.IMPORTAWBs
    join r in context.GODOWNRENTs
      on i.AWBNO equals r.AWBNO into g
    where !g.Any()
    select i;
```

All job will be done on server side, instead of loading all content of `IMPORTAWBs` table and then making additional query for each item in this table. Generated query will look like:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[AWBNO] AS [AWBNO],
    [Extent1].[Foo] AS [Foo]
    [Extent1].[Bar] AS [Bar]
    FROM [dbo].[IMPORTAWBs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[GODOWNRENTs] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[AWBNO] = [Extent2].[AWBNO]
    )
```

Lambda syntax is not that beautiful, but you can nicely use `ToList()` operator here and avoid any local variables:

```
return context.IMPORTAWBs
         .GroupJoin(context.GODOWNRENTs,
                    i => i.AWBNO, r => r.AWBNO, (item, rents) => new { item, rents })
         .Where(x => !x.rents.Any())
         .Select(x => x.item)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for Thank You you are Intelligent !

Comment: @ShahAbdullah thanks, I also added sample of SQL query which will be generated

Comment: var finalizedListForView =
    from i in context.IMPORTAWBs
    join r in context.GODOWNRENTs
      on i.AWBNO equals r.AWBNO into g
    where g.Any()
    select i;

It worked perfectly just removed !(not) with g and fits my requirement thumbs up.